# Fingerprint will not open

Tags: password, fingerprint

My passwords are kept in passwords.google.com. When I am on my Samsung 52 and I need one of my passwords, and I go to Google Password Manager to get it, Android asks me to "verify it's [me]." I understand that I need to get past "use [my] screen lock" so Google knows it's me. I want to use my fingerprint to authenticate, but when I click on the "Continue" button, it says "Screenlock didn't work." I can click on the "Try Again" button, but screen lock doesn't work again, and I get caught in an endless loop of being denied. (There is login with password option, but my password is long and very random and very slow and tedious to type.) This is very frustrating and keeps me from getting my passwords stored by Google on my Google phone. What is the solution/fix for this?

Comment: I assume fingerprint unlocking on regular lock screen works without problems, only within Google Password Manager it makes problems?

Comment: Yes my fingerprint works everywhere else

Comment: Could you clarify on how you access the Google Password Manager? Did you mean from the link https://passwords.google.com/? Or from Settings - Google - Autofill - Autofill with Google - Passwords?